# NodeJS Handle Pop-up with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, popup, puppeteer

For training purposes, from a specific page on Amazon, I'm clicking on a button opening an internal "pop-up".
Thus, Puppeteer doesn't see the pop-up, and I cannot click and handle elements.

Let's start with https://www.amazon.de/ .

Using puppeteer, I'm running:

```
await page.evaluate(() =>{
        document.querySelector('.nav-a.nav-a-2.a-popover-trigger.a-declarative').click();
        }
      });
```

It opens the internal pop-up.

How can I handle this new internal page: to type text in the input box, and click on elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's not a popup but a popover. It will visible and accessible in the DOM after you actually click on the selector

```
await page.evaluate(() =>{
   document.querySelector('.nav-a.nav-a-2.a-popover-trigger.a-declarative').click();
});
```

To unsure you can work with the popover you need to wait to be load.

```
await page.waitForSelector(".a-popover.a-popover-modal.a-declarative");
```

After that you can click and type the text you want in the popover.

Comment: the missing part was the waitForSelector ;-). thanks a lot